# Growth rate of higher order derivatives of a variant of the modular lambda function on the imaginary upper half line

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, elliptic-functions

Let $f(z)=\lambda(-\frac{1}{1+z})=\frac{1}{1-\lambda(z)}$, where $\lambda(z)$ is the modular lambda function, $\lambda(z)=16q-128q^2+704q^3+\ldots$, where $q=e^{\pi i z}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function).

What is the growth rate of the values of higher order derivatives of $f(z)$ for a fixed $z_0$ on the imaginary line?

That is, what is the growth rate of $\frac{d^n f(z)}{dz^n}(z_0)$ for  a fixed $z_0$ as $n\to\infty$, where $z_0\in i \mathbb{R^+}$? In particular, what is the growth rate of $\frac{d^n f(z)}{dz^n}(i)$?

Comment: Do you know any theorems about the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence)?

Comment: Well, since radius of convergence for $z_0=i$ is 1, it allows us to obtain obvious lower and upper bounds of $n! c^{-n}$ and $n! c^n$, where $c>1$. Can we do significantly better than that?